# Define logarithmic function by functional relation

Tags: calculus, functions, definitions, logarithm

My son was working the other day with exercises such as: Find all the mappings $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ verifying

$$\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}, f(m+n)=f(n)+f(m).$$

As another example: Find all the mappings $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}, f(x)f(y)=f(xy)+x+y.$$

I know that there several equivalent ways to introduce the natural logarithmic function but I was wondering how one can define it properly and consicely by means of the functional relation

$$f(xy)=f(x)+f(y).\qquad (1)$$

That is starting from this relation and not any prior knowledge of $\ln$ or $\exp$.
Find all applications $f$ from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that (1) is satisfied, posing all the necessary restrictions.

Thank you very much for any help, or pointing me out if the question is a duplicate.

Comment: Is there a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfying $(1)$? [ I note that logarithms are only $(0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$.]  Let's see ... $f(0)=f(0\cdot y) = f(0)+f(y)$ so $f(y) = 0$ for all $y$.  Easy.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar thanks but I thought I was clear frm this fractional relation the ln imposing all the necessary restrictions.

Comment: Essentially all you need to do is assume continuity, and you will have a logarithm https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710603/functional-equation-unique-solution-logarithm 

Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Comment: This question should be migrated to math.se

Comment: Re *"thanks but I thought I was clear frm this fractional relation the ln imposing all the necessary restrictions"* It's not clear at all what "all the necessary restrictions" mean, and the domain of the function is extremely relevant to determine the set of solutions.

Comment: As Gerald pointed out, if 0 is in the domain of f and f satisfies f(xy) = f(x)+f(y) for all x,y in the domain, then f must be the constant zero function. Likewise for your son's exercise, if 1 is in the domain and f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) for all x,y in the domain, then f(n)=f(1+...+1)=f(1)+...+f(1) = n f(1) for all n in the domain. So the solutions are exactly the set of linear functions; but that's because 1 is in the domain. If the domain was smaller and did not include 1, then you could get extra solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Find all applications $f$ from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
> such that (1) is satisfied, posing all the necessary restrictions.

From the textbook Calculus 9th edition by Salas, Hille, Etgen (section 7.2):

> From our point of view the fundamental property of logarithms is that they transform multiplication into addition: the log of a product = the sum of the logs. Taking this as the central idea, we are led to a general notion of logarithm [...]
>
> DEFINITION 7.2.1 A logarithm function is a nonconstant differentiable function $f$ defined on a set of positive numbers such that for all $a > 0$ and $b > 0$ , $f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$.
>
> Let's assume for the time being that such logarithm functions exist, and let's see what we can find out about them.

After some work they get $f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x} f'(1)$.

> The most natural choice, the one that will keep calculations as simple as possible, is to set $f'(1)=1$.

more discussion

> This function, which takes on the value 0 at 1 and has derivative $1/x$ for $x>0$, must, by Theorem 5.3.5, take the form $\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t}$.

> DEFINITION 7.2.3 The function $L(x) = \int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t}, x > 0$, is called the *(natural) logarithm function*.

Then pages of developing the properties of $L(x)$ before defining the exponential function in section 7.4.

---

Edit (addendum):

> THEOREM 5.3.5 Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$. The function $F$ defined on $[a,b]$ by $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and has derivative $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$.

Comment: Do you want to see how they got from $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$ to $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{x} f'(1)$?